# Pedometer for Expo React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, sensors, pedometer, react-native-sensors

Is there a best recent pedometer library that supports the expo react native project? I'm now using [expo-sensors](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sensors/). however, it appears that it is not yet supported on Android. Thanks ahead of time.

[Here's what I got when I tried it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACtqn.png)

Answer (score 0):

This feature has been deprecated. You can't get the steps between two dates on Android, but I suggest you try Google's FIT API

Comment: But you can downgrade your expo version, and this feature should works fine